# Difficulty sending cookies with fetch requests in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, express

I have two separate services, a `React` single page application and an `express` API and I'm trying to communicate from the SPA to the API using the new `fetch` feature. Since the two services lie on different domains, I'm using a CORS middleware inside of the `express` application in order to make requests from the SPA to the API. I'm trying to make any `fetch` requests also include cookies so that way I can verify the cookies in my `express` application, for example

On the client side:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/hello', { 
    credentials: 'include', 
    mode: 'cors' 
}).then(/* ... */)
```

On the server side:

```
var app = express();

app.use(cors({ credentials: true });
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
  // Try and find the cookies sent with the request
  console.log(req.cookies);

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'cookies received!' });
});
```

However, no matter what I try I still cannot access any cookies on the `request` object even though I can access them through using `document.cookies`.

An example cookie:

```
name: token
value: TOKEN_VALUE
domain: localhost
path: /
http: false
secure: false
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to approach this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it just a typo that you have no closing quote after `credentials: 'include`? Also, do you have a JSFiddle or Pnkr?

Comment: Yeah, sorry! Just a typo. And sadly no because it involves a server-side component.

Comment: Can you share your client side code. I can create my own server.

Comment: The client side code in question mirrors the fetch request that I posted in the question. The request is being fulfilled and I am able to receive responses from my server, but no cookies are being passed to the server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fetch polyfill library you are using is not as of this writing up-to-spec.  For credentials, it expects 'cors' to be the value as opposed to 'include'.  I would edit my local copy of fetch.js on line 264 to accommodate the standard, submit a pull request, and be on the lookout for a better supported polyfill library.

See open issue: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/109

https://github.com/github/fetch

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch

Comment: There are already pull requests on the repo to fix the issue: https://github.com/github/fetch/pull/113/files

Comment: Hi, i had the same issue. changing to 'cors' instead of 'include' didnt solve the problem for me :(

Comment: this is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612226/session-can-not-be-saved-sent-from-fetch-post-request

Comment: I still face the same issue even after using credential as include or same-orgin after using whatg-fetch 2.0.3.

Comment: I must be on the latest version, because 'cors' wasn't valid and fetch threw and error.  This is the spec and I don't see 'cors' as an option?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials