# session does not save after fetch post request with express

Tags: javascript, session, express, cookies

Im making a post request with fetch and saving a token to session in an express api backend. However, the token wont be saved in the session even though i set `credentials` to `include` in fetch. Can anybody identify the problem for me? Thanks.

sending token to api server:

```
 fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      accessToken: user.accessToken,

    })
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

server side:

```
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(cors({credentials: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}));


app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.session.accessToken) {

    req.session.accessToken = req.body.accessToken;
  }
  ...
  ...
})

app.get('/api/users/token', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.session);
  if (req.session.accessToken) {
    return res.json({ accessToken: req.session.accessToken });
  }
  return res.json({ accessToken: null });
})
```

retrieving token from session:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users/token', {
  credentials: 'include' 
})
.then(checkStatus)
.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
.then(json => {
  console.log(json);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

**Edit:**
this is headers from request:

```
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
  accept: '*/*',
  'if-none-match': 'W/"4d-oW2yTGBOs6aaA4LAPgNxNQ"',
  cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3AHXDL6Az0hRZeSGsJgjhw4kvVONBLz-yn.sOOAqbxaLQ6Z%2FfCdfGOmXf9XsYl3JdHvP%2FmfkUln1xA',
  'user-agent': 'cairn/1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.3.0',
  'accept-language': 'en-us',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: false } }
GET /api/users/token 304 23.780 ms - -
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3A1jat379BSZQCKvJV1pKL4_Cub9ApMFVI.m%2BQHkIewMl9Uzjg315GTC5aD5qpWESiQVNDnXrFFSbQ',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'if-none-match': 'W/"270-toaMUba3dhoaPENGp5EGaA"',
  accept: 'application/json',
  'accept-language': 'en-us',
  'content-length': '484',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'user-agent': 'cairn/1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.3.0' }
```

Comment: What happens if you call those server side endpoints using a browser?

Comment: @Leventix i get same result.

Comment: Try removing the `cookieParser` middleware, or give it the same secret as `session`.  If that doesn't work, try `console.log` the request headers and body on each request.  maybe your cookie isn't being sent by the client

Comment: @jwags i think the issue comes from the client request. i can save session via hitting endpoints in a browser.

Comment: I think cookie parser might need to be app.use() earlier. This might be because cors might need cookies.

Comment: Same problem here... If you change fetch with a form and submit button then all works...